# string replacement within a for loop using arithmetic variables

Tags: batch-file, math, for-loop, replace

Trying to produce a cycling list of filenames, starting with a base file and then cycling through an unlimited number of 'sub' files. For example, procedure should produce:

```
Layout.txt
SubLayout{1}.txt
SubLayout{2}.txt
SubLayout{3}.txt
Layout.txt
SubLayout{1}.txt
etc.
```

Where files of the same name exist. `SubLayout{3}.txt` does not exist - therefore loops around to original file. I'm having a problem with the syntax of my string replacement and the arithmetic vars and struggling to get this to work. The code:

```
echo off
set _procRig=Layout.txt
set _sysSub=SubLayout{1}.txt

set _origRig=%_procrig%

:MainProceedureLoop
if "%_procRig%" == "%_origRig%" (
        echo Rig = Original Rig
        set _procRig=%_sysSub%
        set /a _subsubcount=1
    ) else (
    echo Rig is not the original
        set /a "_tempsubcount=_subsubcount"
        set /a "_subsubcount+=1"
        set _tempprocRig=%_procRig:{_tempsubcount}={_subsubcount}%
        echo Rig with replacement: [!_tempprocRig!]
        if exist "C:\tests\!_tempprocRig!" (
                echo Rig exists
                set _procRig=!_tempprocRig!
            ) else (
                echo Rig doesn't exist
                set _procRig=%_origRig%
            )
    )

echo Out: [%_procRig%]
pause
goto :MainProceedureLoop
```

I think the offending line is:

```
 set _tempprocRig=%_procRig:{_tempsubcount}={_subsubcount}%
```

The original code doesn't have gotos, but just amended here for illustration. Would appreciate any help.

---

Update: See comments in Magoos post for background. Code update (still not resolved):

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::Set 
set _procRig=Layout.txt
set _sysSub=SubLayout{1}.txt
set _origRig=%_procrig%
:: Stuff....
:: (_procRig can potentially change during "Stuff" - hence _origRig)
:Loop_For_Example_only
::Dummy conditional:
pause
call :Cycle_filenames
echo Return Vars:
echo _procRig: [%_procRig%]
echo _subsubcount: [%_subsubcount%]
goto :Loop_For_Example_only
exit /b

:Cycle_filenames
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
echo --------------------------------
echo Vars In:
echo _procRig: [%_procRig%]
echo _origRig: [%_origRig%]
echo _subsubcount: [%_subsubcount%]

if "%_procRig%" == "%_origRig%" (
        echo Rig = Original Rig
        echo Syssub: [%_sysSub%]
        set _procRig=%_sysSub%
        set /a _subsubcount=1
    ) else (
    echo Rig is not the original
        echo sub: %_subsubcount%
        pause
        set /a "_tempsubcount=%_subsubcount%"
        set /a "_subsubcount+=1"
        call set _tempprocRig=%%_procRig:{!_tempsubcount!}={!_subsubcount!}%%
        echo Rig with replacement: [%_tempprocRig%]
        if exist "C:\tests\%_tempprocRig%" (
                echo Rig exists
                set _procRig=%_tempprocRig%
            ) else (
                echo Rig doesn't exist
                set _procRig=%_origRig%
            )
    )
echo Out: [%_procRig%]
endlocal && set _procRig=%_procRig%&& set _subsubcount=%_subsubcount%
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've posted "amended" code, it's a little difficult to tell. Your object is not clear.

The line could be changed to this to meet your expectations:

```
CALL set _tempprocRig=%%_procRig:{!_tempsubcount!}={!_subsubcount!}%%
```

but you'd need to un-excise the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

Comment: Thank Magoo. Original code over 7000 lines, hence my pasting a relevant summary. It's true to the original. At which points in the above code do I insert the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `endlocal`?

Comment: **trepidation** - 7000 lines of batch, you're using *delayedexpansion* methods in your posted snippet & you're asking where it need be put? Ideally, just after the `@echo off` at the start of your code - but be aware that you may need to revise any prt of that code that contains `!`. Within the code you've posted, the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` just before `:MainProceedureLoop` and the `endlocal` just after the `goto 
MainProceedureLoop` but that makes no sense since you have a hard loop there. The downside is that the `endlocal` will restore the environment to its state at `setlocal`

Comment: Oh. Think you may have misunderstood my question. I have posted some amended code above which hopefully aids with understanding - more representative of the original code (no gotos - done via call). Posted on original topic Also, tried your suggestion, Magoo, but sadly no joy. Have replace all !s with %s as suggested aside from the ones you specified in the code line. From monitoring - I still think the problem lies with the set _tempprocrig line - as it's setting a null. Any other ideas?

Comment: The way the procedure works is to invoke `delayedexpansion`. In that mode. `!var!` is the run-time value of `var` and `%var%` the parse-time value. When you unaccountably inserted a 'setlocal DISabledelayedexpansion /endlocal` bracket, you turned off the very thing that would make the procedure work. If you remove those statements and use `!_tempprocrig!` within the `if` statement (which ends with the lone `)` 20 lines later) in order to access the *changed* value of `_tempprocrig` then all appears to work....

Comment: Misunderstanding on my part. When you wrote "but you'd need to un-excise the setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" I read this as meaning I had to turn delayed expansion off via `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` I guess I didn't understand the meaning of the word "un-excise." However, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Took a different tac on this and got it working. Only works up to 99 but easily amendable for 100,1000 etc...

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::Set 
set _procRig=Layout
set _sysSub=SubLayout{1}
set _origRig=%_procrig%

:Loop_For_Example_only
::Dummy conditional:
pause
call :Cycle_filenames
echo Return Vars:
echo _procRig: [%_procRig%]
echo _subsubcount: [%_subsubcount%]
goto :Loop_For_Example_only
exit /b

:Cycle_filenames
echo --------------------------------
echo Vars In:
echo _procRig: [%_procRig%]
echo _origRig: [%_origRig%]
echo _subsubcount: [%_subsubcount%]

if "%_procRig%" == "%_origRig%" (
        echo Rig = Original Rig
        echo Syssub: [%_sysSub%]
        set "_procRig=%_sysSub%"
        set /a "_subsubcount=1"
    ) else (
    echo Rig is not the original
        echo sub: %_subsubcount%
        set /a "_tempsubcount=%_subsubcount%"
        set /a "_subsubcount+=1"
        if _subsubcount GEQ 9 (
                set _tempprocRig=!_procRig:~0,-3!
                set _tempprocRig=!_tempprocRig!!_subsubcount!}
            ) else (
                set _tempprocRig=!_procRig:~0,-2!
                set _tempprocRig=!_tempprocRig!!_subsubcount!}
            )
        echo Rig with replacement: [!_tempprocRig!]
        if exist "C:\tests\!_tempprocRig!.txt" (
                echo Rig exists
                set _procRig=!_tempprocRig!
            ) else (
                echo Rig doesn't exist
                set _procRig=!_origRig!
            )
    )
echo Out: [%_procRig%]
goto :eof
```